# MPI and OpenMP Hybrid Program

Tags: c, mpi, openmp, openmpi, hpc

I am trying to run a hybrid OpenMP & MPI program. This is my code that is supposed to parallelize matrix/vector multiplication:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5000

double A[N][N], x[N], y[N], alpha, beta, result[N];

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i, j, error, rank, size;
    double startt, endt;
    error = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    startt=MPI_Wtime();


    int count = N / size; 
    int remainder = N % size;
    int start, stop; 
    int displs[size]; 
    int recv_counts[size]; 


    if(rank<size-1){
        //first n-1 processes do N/size amount of work
        start=rank*(count);
        stop=start+(count-1);
    }

    else if (rank==(size-1)){
        //last process does N/size+N%size amount of work
        start=rank*(count);
        stop=N-1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
            if(i<size-1){
                recv_counts[i] =count;
            }
            else
            {
                recv_counts[i]=count+remainder;
            }
            displs[i] = i*count;

        }

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(A, x, y, alpha, beta, result) private(i, j)  
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; ++i) {
                    result[i] = 0;
                    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
                            result[i] += A[i][j] * x[j];
                    }
            result[i] = alpha * result[i] + beta * y[i];
    }


    MPI_Allgatherv(&result[start], stop-start+1, MPI_DOUBLE,
                                &result[0], recv_counts, displs,
                                MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    endt = MPI_Wtime();
    if(rank==0){
            printf("Done in %f seconds.\n", endt - startt);
    }
    error = MPI_Finalize();
    return  0;
}
```

I compile the program by using `mpicc -openmp test.c -o test`, however, I get the following warning message:
warning: `ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown pragmas-]`

The code seems to work fine without OpenMP. Can anyone give me a hint as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Many compilers require a command-line option to enable OpenMP.  For GCC, for example, you need to specify `-fopenmp` for both compiling and linking.  `mpicc` is probably a wrapper script around the actual compiler, and if you can do what you want at all, then you probably need to find and use the correct OpenMP option for the underlying compiler to get it working.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thank you, I will try that!

Comment: Aside from the obvious issue of the OpenMP compiler switch for which you asked for help, there is a more subtle issue in your code. In there, you are using the table `result` both as sending and receiving buffer in the `MPI_Algatherv()` call. That isn't allowed like this. You have to use `MPI_IN_PLACE` as send buffer instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453564/5239503) for more details.

Comment: If you use a Multi-threaded Program you should use MPI_Init_Thread instead of MPI_Init according to the MPI stndard (with the proper threading level required, wich is MPI_THREAD_FUNNELD in your example)